# Cross table update query in MySql

Tags: mysql, crosstab

I can execute this kind of query in SQL Server:

```
update tblmembers 
set hits_archived = 
  (select count(*) 
   from tblhits 
   where tblhits.target_id=tblmembers.id 
   and tblhits.hitdate < '2009-11-01') 
where tblmembers.regdate < '2007-09-28'
```

How can I do this in MySql 4.0.23?
I tried to execute the query, but it returned this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count(*) from tblhits where tblhits.target_id=tblmem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can also be done with a subquery using MySQL.

[Subquery Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html)

Comment: can you give me a simple example of how to do cross table update with Subquery syntax?

Comment: Hmm you're query looks fine to me. What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Then maybe the problem is described here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,10572,10572#msg-10572 Take a look at the fourth answer. It states that it at least works in vers ion 4.1.8.